# Is there a way to control parallel task groups in airflow? Can we use pools to do that?

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to execute multiple similar tasks for different sets in parallel, but only want to run some of them while making other tasks group wait for completion. For example if I have 5 task groups, I want to run 3 of these groups in parallel and only trigger the others if one of them complete. Basically only have 3 running parallel at a time. What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use ExternalTaskOperator, what it does is bound a task to not run until its parent task is finished you can search on airflow documentation.